# How can I use contains to match exact string?

Tags: angular, typescript, cypress, ui-automation

I'm trying to match exact string using the below code but it seems to be returning all the elements which have same substring.

```
cy.contains('span', 'Apple');
```

I tried using regex as well but that doesn't seem to work as well

```
cy.contains('span', new Regex("^" + "Apple" + "$"))
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex code is correct, but you have a typo in the class name.

It should be `RegExp`.

```js
cy.contains('span', new RegExp("^" + "Apple" + "$"))
  .should('have.text', 'Apple')
```

This passes against simple HTML

```html
<span>Apple</span>
<span>Apple1</span>
<span>2Apple</span>
```

---

But `contains()` only ever returns the ***first*** match, so if you want to assert the count of matches, use a `.filter()` instead.

```js
cy.get('span')
  .filter((i,el) => el.innerText === 'Apple')
  .should('have.length', 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
cy.contains("span", new RegExp("^Apple$", "g"));
```

The second argument of Regexp is the global flag, but you can adapt to your needs.
You can then write a test like that

```
cy.contains("span", new RegExp("^Apple$", "g")).should("have.length", 1)
```